# Insertion order for object of user define class

Tags: java, collections

I am relatively new to Java, and often find that I need to sort a User defined class,s based on some data members. Since the values are not predecided so  they can be unique, I find myself converting the class data member with a custom comparator that sorts on the value associated with the data members. Is there an easier way?

Comment: You are on right track.

Comment: Since the values are not predecided so they can be unique?

Comment: You are doing it right. Custom comparators are meant for what you are doing.

Comment: @ suresh atta Is there any other way of doing it?